# Saving ubuntu 10.04 operating system on disk, with windows 7 theme

Tags: 10.04, iso

Hi all :) I have installed ubuntu 10.04 with WUBI, and was wondering if there is a way to save it as an ISO or OS disk ? I have added the windows 7 theme to it, and its really great !!  I copied and pasted from the internet to the terminal for the windows 7 theme, and would love to save the whole setup for other computers in case that theme is no longer available etc. I always liked windows, but hate the bloat and virus's so this is a perfect fit for me.    Thanx in advance,     Chris

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an ISO of your System or if you just want the theme but none of your installed software download the 10.04 ISO
2. Install Ubuntu Customization Kit
3. Begin to edit the ISO with UCK, then when you get to the UCK shell run `gconf-editor`
4. If you're unsure on how to set the theme and icons from the shell and gconf, open the   gconf-editor from your *own* system and search for "theme".
5. In the UCK shell open a nautilus instance, there navigate to `/usr/share/themes/` and put the Windows theme there.
6. Then in the `gconf-editor` that you opened in the UCK shell simply edit the "theme" entry to match that of your own.

Comment: Thank you Uri :)  Sorry for being so new to this....Creating an ISO of my system is what I would like to do, so the whole thing can be on other PC's. Can I do this with the WUBI (virtual partition) install ?? or would this have to be a Hard Drive install ?? And how ?   Thanks again for taking time to reply  Chris

Comment: You can create an exact ISO of your system with remastersys though it will take  hours.. and I mean  *hours* to complete, so re-downloading the ISO and install the software you have in your System with UCK into the ISO would be faster though you wouldn't have any of your custom options that may have set for each individual programs everything would be at their default.